# Changing second column in csv conditionally

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk, csv

I have a csv file that looks like:

```
data/train/4/36280.png,four
data/train/2/10317.png,two
data/train/2/57890.png,two
data/train/1/53448.png,one
data/train/8/58233.png,eight
data/train/4/23599.png,four
data/train/2/35051.png,two
data/train/1/12323.png,one
data/train/9/18562.png,nine
data/train/8/46629.png,eight
data/train/7/1746.png,seven
```

Where first column is path and second is class. I would like to change the second column conditionally. In pseudo code I want something like:

```
If second column "four" change it to the next row's class
```

So far I've tried just to see if I can change ne class to another, but without success:

```
awk '{ if ($2 == "zero") $2="one"; print $0 }' train.csv > new_file.csv
```

gives me the same csv.

Basically I would like a script that gives me following output csv:

```
data/train/4/36280.png,seven
data/train/2/10317.png,four
data/train/2/57890.png,two
data/train/1/53448.png,two
data/train/8/58233.png,one
data/train/4/23599.png,eight
data/train/2/35051.png,four
data/train/1/12323.png,two
data/train/9/18562.png,one
data/train/8/46629.png,nine
data/train/7/1746.png,eight
```

Comment: The default field separator in awk is whitespace; if you have *comma* separated data, you will need to set the separator accordingly - either with the `-F` command line option, or by setting `FS=","` in a `BEGIN` rule.

Comment: What is "the next rows class" ? Could you please edit your question and add an example output?

Comment: You mean like `awk FS="," '{ if ($2 == "zero") $2="one"; print $0 }' train.csv > new_file.csv´ 
Next row class for line 1 is line 2, column 2. I basically want to shuffle the class in an easy way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bash` solution:

```bsh
readarray -t filename < <(cut -d ',' -f1 train.csv)
readarray -t class < <(cut -d ',' -f2 train.csv)

for (( i=0; i<${#filename[@]}; i++ )); do
    printf '%s,%s\n' "${filename[$i]}" "${class[$((i-1))]}";
done > new_file.csv
```

---

Equivalent `awk` solution:

```
awk -F, '
    {
        filename[NR]=$1
        class[NR]=$2
    }
    END {
        OFS=","
        print filename[1],class[NR]
        for (i=2;i<=NR;i++) {
            print filename[i],class[i-1]
        }
    }
' train.csv > new_file.csv
```

Both solutions first read the lines into arrays `filename` and  `class`. Only difference is that the `bash` array starts with `0`, the `awk` array with `1`.

Then, we loop over the arrays and print the desired output. In the `awk` solution, we need to treat the first line separately as, unlike in `bash`, `array[-1]` does not return the last element.

The `awk` solution is a bit faster.

Comment: I tried it and it looks great! Could I ask how I would save this to a new CSV? I guess its putting > new_file.csv at the end maybe?

Comment: exactly, added to the answer

Comment: Excellent answer, I could not think of any other way then first loading the csv into a RDMS like PostgreSQL